# delegate issues in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @interface AddEventViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

        @end
```

.m file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
    - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;

    @end

    @implementation AddEventViewController

    @synthesize textField1, textField2, textField3;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
    {
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.textField1.delegate = self;
        textField1.delegate = self;


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (textField1)
        {
            if ([textField1 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        }
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

        if (textField2)
        {
            if ([textField2 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
        }
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

        if (textField3)
        {
            if ([textField3 canResignFirstResponder]) [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
        }
        [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
    }


    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;

        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;

        [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    @end

Ok so im getting the yellow bug symbol on the lines:

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];
        self.textField1.delegate = self;
        textField1.delegate = self;
    }
```

I don't know how to delegate all of my textFields? how do i make this textFieldReturn work for all of my textFields.. that viewDidLoad area has to be the problem, because everything else works good...

Comment: Could you post the code in your header file for this class?

Comment: What message are you getting along with the yellow bug symbol?

Comment: Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' from incompatible type 'AddEventViewController *const_strong' @JoelDerfner

Comment: The sole issue was that i had put in <UITextViewDelegate> when I should have put <UITextFieldDelegate>. Changed the code above in my question.. So basically I figured it out thanks to @KevinM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch UITextViewDelegate to UITextFieldDelegate in your header file.  This should do it.  Let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: Wow im stupid. That worked... but still only my first textField keyboard go away.. the other 2 textField's keyboards stay there when i press the 'Done' key.. @KevinM

Answer (score 1):

In .h file set the delegate of `textField` instead of `textView`.
& in .m file replace the following code of `textFieldShouldReturn` method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     if (textField == textField1)
     {
         [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
     }
     else if (textField == textField2)
     {
         [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
     }
     else if (textField == textField3)
     {
         [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
     }
     return YES;
}
```

For textView used following code.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! and while we are at it.. do you know how to change the size of a textField? because I want there to be a Notes textField in my app, and for users to be able to type multiple lines, but when i used a textView, I was having the trouble of not being able to hide the keyboard... so any ideas? @Girish

Comment: I had edited my answer for textView as well try it & let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out! your help was greatly appreciated @Girish

Answer (score 1):

Tag your text fields to differentiate between them inside delegate method. If you dont wish to differentiate then just use the reference you get in the delegate method.

you can use switch if you use tags.

```
 switch(sender.tag)
{

  case <case value>
  //your code
  break;
}
```